# Issue with corr.test() results

Tags: r, statistics

I am running corr.test() to look at potential correlations between genes and bacteria in a dataframe using this code:

```
spearman=cor.test(FullSet$counts.Bac, FullSet$counts.Gene, method="spearman", alternative=c("two.sided"))
```

My dataframe is structured as follows:

| Subject | name.Bac | counts.Bac | name.Gene | counts.Gene |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10C | Finegoldia | -2.07 | CCL4 | 1.73 |
| 10C | Finegoldia | -2.07 | CKAP4 | 6.7 |

In total my dataframe has approximately 4 million rows as I am testing about 2000 genes against 33 bacteria across 24 patients.

When I run the above code I get this as the results:

```
Spearman's rank correlation rho

data:  FullSet$counts.Bac and FullSet$counts.Gene
S = 1.1501e+19, p-value = 8.368e-09
alternative hypothesis: true rho is not equal to 0
sample estimates:
         rho 
-0.002845856
```

However, I was aiming to get the results as a matrix with individual test results and p.values for each comparison so I could plot the results using corrplot(). What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Do you want the correlations between bacteria and genes by subject?

Comment: Not necessarily, all the genes included are differentially expressed so I just want to see if any of the gene expression is associated with higher or lower bacterial counts

Comment: I would run your multiple correlations and then input the results into a dataframe; then I would sort, filter, and plot to find the ones you're actually interested in because you have a lot of combinations. This link might help you get started:  http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/correlation-matrix-a-quick-start-guide-to-analyze-format-and-visualize-a-correlation-matrix-using-r-software

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like the this?
Partition the data by `name.Bac` and `name.Gene`, and run the tests in a `lapply` loop. Then extract the relevant values with a sequence of `sapply` loops and form a results matrix with `cbind`.

```
sp <- split(FullSet, list(FullSet$name.Bac, FullSet$name.Gene))
spearman_list <- lapply(sp, \(x) {
  cor.test(x$counts.Bac, x$counts.Gene, data = x, method = "spearman", alternative = "two.sided")
})

stat <- sapply(spearman_list, `[[`, 'statistic')
pval <- sapply(spearman_list, `[[`, 'p.value')

cbind(stat, pval)
```

Comment: Hi Rui thanks for the comment. Unfortunately your second line of code isn't working. I am getting these errors: ```spearman_list <- lapply(sp, \(x) {
Error: unexpected input in "spearman_list <- lapply(sp, \"
>     cor.test(x$counts.Bac, x$counts.Gene, data = x, method = "spearman", alternative = "two.sided")
Error in cor.test(x$counts.Bac, x$counts.Gene, data = x, method = "spearman",  : 
  object 'x' not found
> })
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"```

Comment: @mrad Time to update your version of R: `\(x)` are the new lambdas introduced in R 4.1 (2021-05-18), and that throw that error in previous versions. In the mean time, try the old lambdas, `function(x)`, they are still in use.